# How to know Debian package install location in postinst/prerm?

Tags: debian, path, packages

The maintainer scripts of Debian package (`debian/postinst`, `debian/prerm`, etc.) can optionally have the *old/new-version* argument, but there's no install dest dir argument. (See [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html))

My package is autotools-based *(autoconf & automake)*, I guess `debuild` configure the package with `DESTDIR=""` and `prefix=/usr`.

Well, though it's uncommon to change `DESTDIR` or `prefix` to other values, but maybe it's useful.

For example, if my package is installed to `/node-136/usr/local`, where `DESTDIR=/node-136` and `prefix=/usr/local`, but how can I know it in the `debian/postinst` script, so I can do the config munging to the correct installation?

Comment: Could you simplify that a little? It's a bit confusing to understand.

Comment: I've rewritten the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. `DESTDIR` and `prefix` are compile-time settings and specific to a particular way of writing a makefile. They have nothing to do with `postinst` which is executed when the package is installed.

Comment: For example, if I want to change config file `$(DESTDIR)/etc/myconfig`, though `debuild` always set `DESTDIR` to empty string at build time, but it can be other values.  One resolution is, add `debian`/ to `SUBDIRS` in `Makefile.am`, and rename `debian/postinst` to `debian/postinst.in` and refer to `@DESTDIR@/etc/myconfig`. But I deem it's not recommended, since `debian/*` is not a part of the source.  Though, `DESTDIR` and `prefix` are compile-time, but `debian/` is not involved in the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess DESTDIR is not used in dh_make.